# Classification of finite subgroup of $PGSp_4(\mathbb{C})$

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, classification

Is there a classification of the finite subgroups of $PGSp_4(\mathbb{C})$?

Comment: These are the same as those in the maximal compact subgroup, $\mathrm{PSp}(4)$, which in turn is (by an exceptional isomorphism) is isomorphic to $\mathrm{SO}(5)$. (So the isomorphism classification is the same, although I'm not completely sure that for a complex semisimple group $G$ with compact maximal subgroup $K$, whether two finite subgroups of $K$ that are conjugate in $G$ are always conjugate in $G$, so I'm not firm about claiming that the classification up to conjugation is the same)

Comment: I search a classification. Example :  the finite subgroups of  $PGL_2(\mathbb{C})$ are the dihedral groups D_2n and A_5 S_4 and S_5 .....   And I want an answer like this or a reference. I didn't speak about compact but finite groups.

Comment: I understand that you asked about finite subgroups. Anyway my comment was about maximal compact subgroups which is the first step towards understanding finite subgroups.

Comment: As someone who isn't a group theorist, I am a bit puzzled by the downvote and the votes to close...

Comment: @YemonChoi The question itself is reasonable. But a little more context would have been good! For example the poster could have included their comment above in the original question.

Comment: Maybe the discussion and references of a related question http://mathoverflow.net/questions/37136/classification-of-finite-groups-of-isometries helps further.