# Can $E_8$ be enlarged?

Tags: gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory, coxeter-groups, symmetry

Is there any finite 8-dimensional point group which contains the $E_8$ Coxeter group as a subgroup other than $E_8$ itself?

Comment: Possibly related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/37136/classification-of-finite-groups-of-isometries

Answer (score 19):

No.

Let $G$ be a finite subgroup of $GL_n(\mathbb R)$ containing $W(E_8)$ as a subgroup. Because $G$ is compact, $G$ must preserve a symmetric positive definite form on $\mathbb R^8$. Since $W(E_8)$ preserves a unique such form, it must be that one.

Let $H$ be the largest subgroup of $G$ generated by reflections. Then $H$ contains $W(E_8)$ and thus is an irreducible reflection group, hence a Coxeter group. Examining the table of Coxeter groups and looking for entries in dimension $8$, there are four possibilities: $W(A_8), W(B_8), W(D_8), W(E_8)$. Because $W(E_8)$ has the highest order of these, we must have $H = W(E_8)$.

Now, by construction, $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, so $G$ normalizes $W(E_8)$, and hence $G$ is contained in the automorphism group of the $E_8$ root system. Because the Coxeter-Dynkin diagram $E_8$ has no nontrivial automorphisms, this is $W(E_8)$ and so $G= W(E_8)$, as desired.

Comment: In the last step, why should $G$ be a semidirect product? Even if it is, why should it inject into $\mathrm{Aut}E_8$? Also, $E_8$ does have a non-trivial outer automorphism (taking reflections to their negation). Diagram automorphisms induce group automorphisms, but are not always outer nor do they always exhaust the outer automorphisms.

Comment: @GrantB. I said nothing about semidirect products. We can describe the $E_8$ root system as the set consisting of, for each reflection in $E_8$, the two vectors of length $2$ which are eigenvectors of the reflection with eigenvalue $1$. This makes it clear that any $G$ which normalizes $E_8$ stabilizes the $E_8$ root system, and hence, because there are no Dynkin diagram automorphisms, lies in $W(E_8)$.

Comment: @GrantB. Said to work in the generality of Coxeter groups, rather than just ADE type root systems: Consider the division of $\mathbb R^n$ by hyperplanes fixed by the reflections in a Coxeter group $H$. This splits $\mathbb R^n$ into a union of alcoves, on which $H$ and $N(H)$ (the normalizer of $H$ in $O(N)$, not its outer automorphism group) act. But $H$ acts transitively on alcoves because we can use the appropriate reflection to connect adjacent chambers, so every element of $N(H)$ is an element of $H$ times a stabilizer of your favorite alcove - i.e. an automorphism of the Coxeter diagram.

Comment: @GrantB. Negation IS an element of the Coxeter group $E_8$. Specifically, it is the longest element. In general, negation is contained in a finite Coxeter group if and only if all of its exponents (see https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Coxeter_group ) are odd.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer The issue is that every Coxeter group containing negation has an outer automorphism which sends every reflection to minus that reflection, and this isn't an automorphism coming from the Coxeter group or diagram automorphisms (except possibly in dimension 2), because it doesn't even preserve the characteristic polynomials of the reflections. Of course, this is not so relevant here, because we're interested in automorphisms coming form linear transformations only.

Comment: I am sure we basically agree, but I don't quite follow how you are saying it. If $-1$ is NOT in the Coxeter group, then $(-1) \circ w_0$ permutes the simple roots nontrivially and gives rise to a diagram automorphism. Thus, if there are no diagram automorphisms (as in the case of $E_8$), we can be sure that $-1$ is in the group. But there are cases which have diagram automorphisms, and yet $-1$ is in the group: This happens for $D_{2k}$. I thought I'd give the exact criterion for $-1$ to be in the group.

Comment: One way to see this is the ring of invariants is generated in degrees $e_1+1$, $e_2+1$, ..., $e_n+1$, where the $e_j$ are the exponents, so "all $e_j$ odd" is equivalent to "all invariant functions are in even degree" is equivalent to "all invariant functions are invariant for $-1$" is equivalent to "$-1$ is in the group".

Comment: @Will Ahh, I missed the phrase "root system" when I was reading, my mistake! Your follow-up clarifies the role of the normalizer in O(n), thank you!

Comment: @David Right, I agree that $-1=w_0$ is in $E_8$, but the automorphism given by $s_i\mapsto -s_i$ is still outer, since for instance the trace of each reflection changes sign.

Comment: @GrantB. Okay, now I understand. You are right (and Will is also right).