# Classification of maximal point groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, symmetry

Have the maximal (without finite proper overgroups of the same dimensionality) finite point groups been fully classified in any dimensionality of Euclidean space greater than 4?

Comment: Are you asking if there is a classification of maximal finite subgroups of the orthogonal group of Euclidean space, for Euclidean space of dimension 5 or more? Clearly all finite groups act as subgroups of the orthogonal group in some dimension.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I’m asking.

Comment: [Here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/383713/108884) I asked this question for reflection groups. Not every point group is a subgroup of a reflection group (an example in dimension four is given [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/349139)). But is it clear that this is still true in sufficiently large dimension?

Comment: Yes. In 4n dimensions there is the Cartesian product of n 4D counterexamples.

Comment: @DanielSebald Sure, but those are probably as easy to handle as the initial counterexample. I meant whether there are always "essentially new" such counterexamples.