# Can the infinite von Dyck groups be subgroups of $SU(n)$?

Tags: gr.group-theory

I asked this over stackexchange with no answer so here we are,

I know by constructing some particular cases that I can find unitary matrices $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ such that

$X^m = Y^n = Z^p = XYZ = 1$

with

$$
\frac{1}{m} + \frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{p} < 1
$$

indicating an infinite von Dyck group unless the fact that the matrices are unitary implies some additional, non-trivial relations between $X$, $Y$ and $Z$. Is it possible for infinite von Dyck or triangle groups to be subgroups of $SU(n)$?

Also, can somebody point to me some references on representation theory of infinite discrete groups?

Comment: They are subgroups of $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ are they not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The question was somewhat sloppy so it was unclear if it was about *some* or *all* von Dyck groups admitting embeddings in $U(n)$. If the question was *some* then Victor's answer clearly suffices.

If the question was about *all* von Dyck groups, then Victor's answer almost gets there but not quite, since only finitely many of these groups are arithmetic (first observed by Takeuchi who actually listed them all, but also follows from far more powerful finiteness theorem of Borel and Prasad: Only finitely many arithmetic groups with covolume $\le const$).
For non-arithmetic groups one has to worry about all Galois conjugations yielding noncompact forms of $SO(3)$. For non-arithmetic groups, one has to use a bit more elaborate version of Victor's answer. First, observe that every von Dyck group $\Lambda$ contains a closed surface subgroup $\Gamma$ of finite index. I will consider only the case when the genus is $\ge 2$ since virtually abelian case is much easier. Then, being a closed surface group,  $\Gamma$ is isomorphic to a cocompact arithmetic subgroup $\Gamma'$ of $O(2,1)$. Now, $\Gamma'$ admits an embedding $\rho$ to some $U(n)$ as explained by Victor. To embed (unitarily) the original group $\Lambda$, use the representation induced from $\rho: \Gamma\to U(n)$ to $\Lambda$.

A more interesting question is if every finitely generated subgroup of $SL(n, {\mathbb R})$ embeds in some orthogonal group. It seems that $SL(m, {\mathbb Z})$ is a counter-example for that.

Update: a. Indeed, $SL(n, {\mathbb Z})$ does not embed in any $U(m)$. The same applies to all  finitely generated groups which contain distorted cyclic subgroups, see Yves' comments. The simplest example will be Baumslag-Solitary groups $BS(1,p)=\langle a, b| aba^{-1}=b^p\rangle$, $p>1$.

b. There is no way to construct sytematically *all* irreducible finite dimensional unitary representations of von Dyck groups since (starting in certain dimension) there will be continuous families of such representations. (The situation is very much unlike theory of Lie groups.) One way to see this is by observing that the spaces of irreducible unitary representations (modulo conjugation) of surface groups have positive dimension. Using induction (of representations) one can then prove the same for von Dyck groups.

Here are few links where one can read about surface group representations (including unitary ones):

http://www.math.u-psud.fr/~labourie/preprints/pdf/surfaces.pdf

http://arxiv.org/pdf/math.GT/0509114.pdf

http://arxiv.org/abs/0710.5263

The old paper by Andre Weil "Remarks on Cohomology of Groups" 
http://www.jstor.org/stable/1970495 is particularly relevant for the discussion of von Dyck groups $\Gamma$, since Weil computes dimension of the Zariski tangent space of $Hom(\Gamma, G)$ in the end of the paper, where $G$ is an arbitrary Lie group. (He does much more, of course.)

c. One can show that every hyperbolic von Dyck group $D(p,q,r)$, except for $D(2,6,6)$ and $D(2,4,6)$, admits a homomorphism to $PU(2)$ whose image is dense. In particular, for every von Dyck group $\Gamma$ (with the above exceptions), one gets an irreducible representation to $U(n), n\ge 3$. By working more carefully, one can probably prove the same for the two exceptions.

d. Situation with irreducible representations to $SU(2)$ is more complicated: There will be more exceptions.

Comment: Thank you for filling in some details, Misha! The construction with surface groups is really much easier (although one then needs to pull orthogonal representations of *these* groups out of a hat). 

What is the history of question in the last paragraph, is it a known problem? 

Comment: Victor, I do not know, I just thought about it while typing my answer. 

Comment: A couple of thoughts, then: 1. GL(n) embeds diagonally into split O(n,n); 2. Superrigidity.

Comment: If $SL(n,Z)$, $n>2$ maps to $SO(m)$ then unipotents are mapped to distorted elements and therefore to finite order elements. Bounded generation of $SL(n,Z)$ (which is not trivial but much easier that the normal subgroup theorem or superrigidity) implies that the image is finite.

Comment: About the question: the induction argument shows that if a group G has a finite index k subgroup H having a faithful representation in some O(n) then so does G. Induce a faithful rep of H to G. Get a representation; it's possibly not faithful but is faithful in restriction to G, but we can fix this by also considering a faithful rep of the finite group G/H. (In particular, G embeds into O(kn+k-1).)  Note that in case G has no nontrivial finite normal subgroup intersecting H trivially then the induced representation is faithful for free.

Comment: Thanks, Yves! My argument for $SL(n, {\mathbb Z})$ was more complicated and used superrigidity. Your argument is much better since it proves (finite-dimensional) non-unitarizability for all f.g. groups with distorted cyclic subgroups.  

Comment: Thanks Misha and Yves, the question referred in fact to all von Dyck groups - or at least a large quantity of them. So this answers that part. The other part of the question referred to representations. I don't mind representations being not faithful. The question comes from physics where faithful is not important. I do require them being irreducible. Do the von Dyck groups have irreducible representations of the same dimension than those of $SO(3)$?

Comment: @whistles: You have to be more precise with your questions, including the last one. Was it (a) that for every hyperbolic von Dyck group $D$ there exists $n$ so that both $D$ and $SO(3)$ admit an irreducible representation of dimension $n$? (Answer is "yes".) Or was it (b) that for every hyperbolic von Dyck group $D$ and for every $n$-dimensional irreducible representation of $SO(3)$ there exists an irreducible $n$-dimensional representation of $D$? (The answer is probably "no" already for $n=3$, but requires some computations to check.) Hope you understand that (a) and (b) are different.

Comment: @whistles: Three facts you need to know about representations of von Dyck groups $D(q_1,q_2,q_3)$ to $SO(3)$: They are parameterized by spherical triangles with angles $A_1,A_2,A_3$ of the form 
$A_i=\frac{k_i\pi}{q_i}$, where $k_i$ are positive integers. Necessary and sufficient conditions for existence of a spherical triangle with angles $A_i$ are: (i) angle sum $>\pi$ (Gauss-Bonnet) and (ii) triangle inequalities for the dual angles $A_i^*=\pi-A_i$ [see M.Berger, "Geometry"]. (3) Irreducible representations are equivalent to $A_i\ne 0, \pi$ and at most one right angle among $A_i$'s.     

Comment: I wrote a comment before, here is a better version of it. First of all thanks for taking interest in the question. Then, to your first comment, I hope that you understand that it is evident that (a) and (b) are different. Also, I consider (a) to be rather trivial once the original question has a positive answer. The question was (b) and what I want to know in general, without making any referencing to any embedding in a Lie group, is how to construct systematically ALL representations of von Dyck groups, or triangle groups for what matters just like it is known how to do it for Lie groups...

Comment: @Misha with respect to your second comment, there's something that I don't understand. For any given $q_1,q_2,q_3$ there's only a finite number of spherical triangles with angles of the form $A_i=\frac{k_i \pi}{q_i}$ so if I understand correctly, this implies that there are only a finite number of irreducible representations of von Dyck groups that can be embedded in $SO(3)$? But if I have one embedding into, say the defining representation of $SO(3)$, then there's a map that takes elements of a von Dyck group to matrices of any irrep of $SO(3)$, of which there's an infinite number...

Comment: that is, I will have matrices of dimension d that generate the von Dyck group for any $d$. Are you saying that these are reducible? A simple question: the number of irreducible representations of a von Dyck group is infinite, is it not? – whistles 0 secs ago

Comment: @whistles: I updated my answer to address some of your questions. Your question "only a finite number of irreducible representations of von Dyck groups that can be embedded in SO(3)" is poorly phrased. The correct statement is that there are only finitely many homomorphisms from von (any) Dyck group to $SO(3)$ (up to conjugation). Once you have a representation $\rho: \Gamma\to SO(3)$ and an irreducible representation $\pi: SO(3)\to U(n)$, then you also have compositions $\phi=\pi\circ \rho$. Some of them may fail to be irreducible. However, if $\rho(\Gamma)$ is dense, $\phi$ is irreducible. 

Comment: @whistles: Answer to your simple question "the number of irreducible representations of a von Dyck group is infinite, is it not?" is "yes", furthermore, the cardinality is continuum. See item (b) of my updated answer. Finiteness holds for $SO(3)$ (and $SO(4)$) but fails in sufficiently higher dimensions. Here is a guess: 

*Conjecture.* For every hyperbolic von Dyck's group $\Gamma$ there exists a number $N$ so that for every $n\ge N$ the variety $Hom(\Gamma, U(n))$ contains (nonconstant) curves consisting of inequivalent irreducible representations. 

 

Answer (score 6):

Yes, such embeddings of von Dyck groups (and more generally, of discrete isometry groups of hyperbolic space) can be constructed with the standard machinery from algebraic groups and lattices. Here is a sketch of the construction, but for the sake of simplicity, I'll describe the orthogonal case and only describe the case of the quadratic field. The whole construction, with attributions, is explained well in Lubotzky's book (see also Borel-Wallach). You can treat it as a black box that allows you to embed a subgroup of a group of orthogonal matrices with signature $(n,1)$ and entries in a quadratic field $K$ into the real orthogonal group $O(n+1).$

Let $q$ be the diagonal quadratic form $\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} a_i x_i^2,$ where $a_i$ are non-zero elements of a real quadratic field $K$, and $G=O(q)$ be the isometry group of $q$ viewed as an algebraic group. Denote by $\sigma$ the non-trivial Galois automorphism of the field $K$ and assume that $a_i$ is totally positive for $1\leq i\leq n,$ but $a_{n+1}$ is not. The group $G(K)$ of $K$-points of $G$ embeds into $O(n)\times O(n,1).$ In a plain language, $g\in G(K)$ is a matrix with entries in $K$ that preserves the form $q,$ and it is mapped into the pair of real matrices $(g,g^{\sigma}),$ where $g$ preserves a positively definite quadratic form $q$ and $g^{\sigma}$ preserves the quadratic form $q^{\sigma}$ of signature $(n,1).$ More precisely, by the restriction of scalars from $K$ to $\mathbb{Q}$, $G$ embeds into a product of orthogonal groups over $\mathbb{Q}$ with real forms $O(n+1)$ and $O(n,1),$ and this embedding leads to an embedding $f$ of $G(K)$ into the product of real groups $O(n+1)\times O(n,1).$ Moreover, the composition of $f$ with the projection onto the first factor is an embedding $f'$ of $G(K)$ into $O(n+1).$

Although von Dyck groups are not necessarily arithmetic, they are defined over $\bar{\mathbb{Q}},$ and some of them over quadratic fields. Thus you can embed them into $SO(3),$ although, of course, the image is dense.

A standard example is $q=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 +\sqrt{5}x_{n+1}^2,$ with $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5}).$ The conjugate form $q^{\sigma}= \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 -\sqrt{5}x_{n+1}^2,$
and it's clear that $q$ is positively definite and $q^\sigma$ has signature $(n,1).$ I think, although I haven't checked the details, that the case $n=2$ takes cares of the von Dyck group $(2,5,5).$

Comment: Thanks Victor. Very useful answer. Does Lubotsky book treat the subject of representations of von Dyck groups?

Comment: One question Victor, how does this answer fits with the answer by David Speyer in this question http://mathoverflow.net/questions/61682/classification-of-discrete-subgroups-of-the-unitary-group saying that every discrete subgroup of $U(n)$ is finite?

Comment: All these embedding have nondiscrete image: You can start with a discrete group and then embed it as a nondiscrete subgroup in another Lie group. 