# Finite subgroups of compact simple Lie groups

Tags: lie-groups, finite-groups

The finite subgroups of $SU(2)$ consist of the symmetry groups of the Platonic solids plus the finite subgroups of $O(2)$.  I would like to know if there are any results concerning $SU(3)$.  In general, are there classification results as to the finite subgroups of compact simple Lie groups over $\mathbb{C}$?

**Update:** Thanks everyone for the references.

Comment: There is a beautiful and informative Bourbaki talk by Serre on the subject of finite subgroups of Lie groups. That's a good place to look.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Do you have a link/name? I looked for a short while without success...

Comment: https://eudml.org/doc/110267

Comment: Googling "finite subgroups of $\text{SU}(3)$" gave me http://arxiv.org/abs/1101.2308 and http://mathoverflow.net/questions/17072/the-finite-subgroups-of-sun, which I guess this question is more or less a duplicate of.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Thanks much!