# The probability that two elements of a finite nonabelian simple group commute

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, pr.probability, finite-groups

It is mentioned in [here](https://infoscience.epfl.ch/record/126007/files/Robinson%202.pdf) (last paragraph of the first page) that Dixon proved the following result: the probability that two elements of a finite nonabelian simple group commute is at most $\frac{1}{12}$. I cannot seem to find this proof anywhere online. Do you know a proof of this fact? Or do you have a reference for it? (I am actually more interested in the original proof)

Comment: In fact, for any $\epsilon$, there will be at most finitely many simple groups $G$ with $cp(G) \geq \epsilon$. This follows from Dixon's argument (linked below) and the fact that for any $n$ there are at most finitely many finite simple groups with an irreducible representation of dimension $n$. See e.g. https://mathoverflow.net/a/27365/1345

Comment: In fact, that can be proven without the use of any representation theory. Let $c(G)$ denote the number of conjugacy classes of the finite group $G$, so that $cp(G) \geq \epsilon$ means $\frac{c(G)}{|G|} \geq \epsilon$. Then if $k$ is the size of the smallest non-identity conjugacy class of $G$, comparing that with the average size of one of them gives us $k \leq \frac{|G|-1}{c(G)-1}$. Since $c(G) \geq 5$ for any nonabelian finite simple $G$ (in fact, $c(G) \leq 4$ implies $|G| \leq 12$), we get $k < \frac{5|G|}{4c(G)} \leq \frac{5}{4\epsilon}$. Then remember $G$ acts faithfully on $k$ points.

Comment: Clarifying: I meant that $c(G) \leq 4$ and $G$ finite imply $|G| \leq 12$.

Answer (score 8):

You can find Dixon's argument [here (Google Books).](https://books.google.com/books?id=SeEZyKYvMwMC&pg=PA302&lpg=PA302&dq=J.%20D.%20Dixon,%20Solution%20to%20Problem%20176,%20Canadian%20Mathematical%20Bulletin,%2016%20(1973),%20302.&source=bl&ots=NIvk6q2Wlu&sig=64FTWLUQoU6B86De9ncFCv8yPDw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjIt83zksbdAhVG0oMKHebLA0kQ6AEwAHoECAAQAQ#v=onepage&q=J.%20D.%20Dixon%2C%20Solution%20to%20Problem%20176%2C%20Canadian%20Mathematical%20Bulletin%2C%2016%20(1973)%2C%20302.&f=false) *(J.D..Dixon, Solution to Problem 176, Canadian Mathematical Bulletin 16 (1973), p302.)*

Comment: Note that Dixon's argument can be simplified a little. No finite simple group can have an irreducible complex character of degree $2$. If $G$ were a simple group with such a representation, then $|G|$ would be even (since irreducible character degrees divide the group order). Then $G$ would contain an involution $t$ by Cauchy's theorem, and $t$ would be in $Z(G)$ since $t$ would be represented by $-I$ (on consideration of determinant), contrary to simplicity.