# Where can I learn about the discrete symmetries of the complex projective plane (or space)?

Tags: complex-geometry, projective-geometry, symmetry

I understand that $CP^1$ is the Riemann Sphere. I guess all its discrete symmetries were known for a long time and well-classified. (But suggestions or good references where this is worked out in a neat way would be appreciated.)

My question is: I want to know about the discrete symmetries of $CP^2$ and more generally, also $CP^n$. Is there any place these are worked out in a simple way?

Are there any classical references specifically about the complex projective plane?

Comment: What do you mean by 'discrete' symmetries? The usual symmetries of $\mathbb{C}P^1$ are the Mobius transformations, that form the Lie (i.e. non-discrete) group $PGL(2,\mathbb C)$. In general the symmetry group of $\mathbb{C}P^n$ is $PGL(n+1,\mathbb C)$.

Comment: Are you asking for a classification of discrete subgroups of $\mathrm{PGL}(n+1,\mathbb{C})$?

Comment: I guess I want to know all the discrete subgroups of PGL(n+1,C), and possibly interpret them geometrically, like regular polyhedra.

Comment: Every finite group appears as automorphisms of some complex projective space, so you need a more precise question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The finite subgroups of SU(n)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/17072/the-finite-subgroups-of-sun)