# The number of uniformly finite subgroups of some Lie groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be the group $SO(n)$, $SU(n)$ or $Sp(n)$.

Let $F_m$ be the collection of finite subgroups of $G$ such that its order is bounded by $m$. Two elements in $F_m$ are identified if they are conjugate in $G$.

Can we prove that $\#F_m \le C(n,m)$ for some finite number $C(n,m)$?

Comment: See this question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/17072/the-finite-subgroups-of-sun

Comment: I am sure this was asked earlier; indeed, there are only finitely many finite subgroups of the given order in each connected Lie group up to conjugation.

Comment: It amounts to showing that for every finite group $F$ there are finitely many conjugacy classes of homomorphisms $F\to G$. This is a standard fact, at least in the OP's setting. For instance this is explicit in [D.H. Lee, T.S. Wu. On conjugacy of homomorphisms of topological groups. Illinois J. Math. 13 1969 694-699], but already follows from Weil's rigidity (1964), and was possibly known earlier. (For the general case: use conjugacy of maximal compact subgroups —due to Iwasawa— to reduce to the compact case.)