# Reference request: type C, D Catalan numbers

Tags: co.combinatorics

[Catalan numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number) are generalized to type B: https://oeis.org/A000984.

Are there some references about Catalan numbers of type C, D? Thank you very much.

Comment: You may find this question and its references interesting https://mathoverflow.net/questions/17197/how-does-this-relationship-between-the-catalan-numbers-and-su2-generalize

Comment: see https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0111053

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Catalan numbers you get in types other than A depend on which interpretation of the Catalan numbers you are generalizing.  There are at least two possibilities: the number of anti-chains in the root poset (these are sometimes called non-nesting partitions) gives the so called Coxeter-Catalan number; these are well-studied, see e.g. "A uniform bijection between nonnesting and noncrossing partitions" by Armstrong, Stump, and Thomas.  The number of Stembridge's "fully commutative" elements (in type A, this is the same as 321-avoiding permutations) of the Coxeter group is another generalization which gives different numbers, see "The enumeration of fully commutative elements of coxeter Groups" by Stembridge for explicit generating functions in all types.

Comment: thank you very much. Are there some generalized Catalan number of type B such that the seqnece of the numbers is $3,9,29,97,333$ for $n=2,3,4,5,6$? It seems that the two generalization you gave do not give this sequence.

Comment: Your sequence appears [in OEIS](http://oeis.org/search?q=3%2C9%2C29%2C97%2C333&language=english&go=Search).  The generating function looks similar to the one for Catalan numbers, and according to one of the comments it is a "Catalan transform" of the Fibonacci numbers.